# CMake generation fails on VS 2019 C# Project

Tags: c#, cmake, visual-studio-2019

Using VS 2019, my CMake CSharp project complains:

```
CMAKE_CSharp_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
```

and

```
C# is currently only supported for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and later
```

after generation. The following files have been used:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(test_proj CSharp)

include(CSharpUtilities)
set(CMAKE_CSharp_FLAGS "/langversion:latest")

add_executable("test"
    main.cs
)
set_target_properties("test" PROPERTIES
    LINKER_LANGUAGE CSharp
    VS_DOTNET_TARGET_FRAMEWORK_VERSION "v4.5"
    VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES
        "Microsoft.CSharp;
        System;
        System.Core;
        System.Data;
        System.Data.DataSetExtensions"
)
```

CMakeSettings.json:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "x64-Release",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "configurationType": "Release",
      "buildRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\\CMakeBuilds\\${workspaceHash}\\build\\${name}",
      "installRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\\CMakeBuilds\\${workspaceHash}\\install\\${name}",
      "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
      "buildCommandArgs": "-v",
      "ctestCommandArgs": "",
      "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x64_x64" ],
      "variables": []
    }
  ]
}
```

It seems that the problem may related to `Ninja` generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message describes why this is not working:

```
C# is currently only supported for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and later.
```

This is because CMake's support for C# **only** works if you select the generator to be Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 or later. Here is the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/release/3.8.html#c) from the CMake site when they released their C# support:

> CMake learned to support CSharp (C#) as a first-class language that can be enabled via the `project()` and `enable_language()` commands. **It is currently supported by the Visual Studio Generators for VS 2010 and above.**

This is still the case with the latest versions of CMake available at the time of writing, and it will not work with the Ninja generator. Just change your generator to VS 2019:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "x64-Release",
      "generator": "Visual Studio 16 2019",
      ...
```

Comment: I test you solution `"generator": "Visual Studio 16 2019"` but another error shows: `Could not create named generator Visual Studio 16 2019 Win64`! I can't understand why VS add `Win64` to the generator. my CMake version is 3.14.

Comment: Updating from VS 16.0 to 16.3.6 solve the problem when using `"generator": "Visual Studio 16 2019 Win64"`